# Applicant response to Pre-Exam Formalities Notice

Tags: uspto, my-uspto

I was asked to file several documents that weren't contained in my provisional patent application. To E-File the documents, the letter must include a "Applicant response to Pre-Exam Formalities Notice".

Where do I find that document, and where should I submit everything? Haven't been able to find that information in the E-Filling system.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a customer number? Customer numbers are available to anyone and allow use of the electronic system beyond the initial filing.

Comment: Yes, I have a costumer number.

Comment: Have you checked Private PAIR?

Comment: It seems like the private pair is down. The patent center says it has 100% of the functionality of private pair. Can I do it there?

Comment: I retired as a patent agent when there still a public pair and no patent center yet but so I assume yes.

Comment: have you found the document? if so, let me know how you did. I'm struggling to find the same document.